# How to add specific height of an element to another

Tags: jquery, get, height

I've got html code like that:

```
<section>
   <div>
   </div>
</section>
<section>
   <div>
   </div>
<section>
```

I don't have specific height of any of element.
And what i wanna to do is to get the section height and give it to the inner div height. How can i do this with jQuery?

I've already tryed something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var contentHeight = $('.content').parent().height();
    $(".content").height(contentHeight);
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    var contentHeight = $('.content').parent().height();
    $(".content").height(contentHeight);
});
```

but it only takes the height of a first section and then apply it to all of the inner divs.

Comment: Add `.content { height: 100%; }` in CSS

Comment: Can you provide any example where your expected behaviour would be useful because honestly, i don't see any for the moment. And if you change content height, depending margin/padding, it would modify parent height, so what are you expecting in this case???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$(window).resize` section, replace your code with this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".content").each(function(){
      $(this).css('height', $(this).parent().height()+'px');
    });
});
```

The reason that only the first `".content"` is affected, is that your `$('.content')` returns an **array** of matching elements, but the `.height()` part only returns the **first** element of that array. The solution is to iterate through the **entire** set of `".content"` elements using `.each(function(){...})`

Comment: the .each was what i was looking for :) thanks a lot :)

Comment: Then accepting my answer is the right thing to do :-)

Comment: As a side note, you don't really need the `each`, `css()` method can be used to loop, using function parameter: `$(".content").css('height', function () {
    return $(this).parent().height();
});`  But again, i don't see any relevant purpose for this

Comment: @A.Wolff I agree, but the purpose here is to answer him and help him, not criticizing his design...

Comment: @RonenCypis Ya you are correct but constructive citics can usually be more useful than workaround for bad design. But anyway, you fixed OP's issue, so get my point (10 points)... :)